# Is "ref.off()" the correct approach to disconnect from Firebase Database after reading data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We have scenarios where we read data from the Firebase Database and then disconnect (we do not care to receive updates on that data). We use code like the snippet below:

```
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    // Display the data
  });
});
```

We use `ref.once()` because we care to read the data all at once, we understand that there's monitoring set on the data nonetheless by Firebase.

What's the best approach to stop the monitoring, and should we even attempt that in an effort to reduce resources consumed, etc.? We tried `ref.off()` and that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: To stop monitoring, disconnect your listeners, either by attaching them with `once()` or by calling `off()`. To disconnect, call `disconnect()`. The two are not related (in the JavaScript client)(at the moment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [official document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once), you don't need to call `off()`.

> In some cases you may want a snapshot of your data without listening for changes, such as when initializing a UI element that you don't expect to change. You can use the once() method to simplify this scenario: **it triggers once and then does not trigger again.**
>
> This is useful for data that only needs to be loaded once and isn't expected to change frequently or require active listening. For instance, the blogging app in the previous examples uses this method to load a user's profile when they begin authoring a new post:

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
var username = snapshot.val().username;
// ...
});
```